# Nginx and PHP-FPM 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm

I'm using Nginx with PHP-FPM. The requested page is displayed, but firebug shows that the paths to the CSS, JS, and images are returning 403 Forbidden error which breaks the styling.

Taking a look at the logs:

```
013/03/09 21:15:43 [error] 1012#0: *17 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Access to the script '/var/www/my_server/extras/extras/go/_common/imgs/WebLogo2-trans.png' has been denied (see security.limit_extensions)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 33.33.33.1, server: my-server.com, request: "GET /extras/extras/go/_common/imgs/WebLogo2-trans.png HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/tmp/php-fpm.sock:", host: "www.my-server.com", referrer: "http://www.my-server.com/extras/better/"
```

However, I tried setting `security.limit_extensions = .php .css .js .jpg` just to see what happens, but the mimetype is interpreted is text/html and doesn't load.

I've tried chmod 777 every file and directory, but no luck.

Here is the Nginx server block: http://dpaste.com/1017993/ and relevent location block. The location block is included from another file which is not reflected in the server block:

```
     location /extras/ {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/my_server/extras.log debug_phpfpm;
            include         /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            root            /var/www/my_server/extras;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            autoindex       on;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;

            expires max;

    }
```

My `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`;

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

The output of `/usr/sbin/php5-fpm -version`:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.5 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jan 18 2013 23:44:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with XCache v1.3.2, Copyright (c) 2005-2011, by mOo
```

Nginx 1.2.6 is compiled from source for extra modules.

Comment: Please include the complete `server` block at issue here.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here's the server block: http://dpaste.com/1017993/

Comment: The `location` block you gave above doesn't even appear in there! Please start over from the beginning.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's included in another file called medias.inc, but it's hundreds of lines long so I took out the relevant section for simplicity. Also, requests are being sent to PHP-FPM because the page is displayed, but static files are returning 403 Forbidden.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I updated the paths. The only thing I did was substitute `my_server`to obscure which site it's for. I would appreciate it if you could enumerate the problems with the config. I'm aware that `root /nonexistent` is one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to presume you've given enough information and not left out anything *important* in the nginx configuration information you chose not to share.

With that caveat in mind...

---

It appears that you are passing *everything* under `/extras/` to PHP, including requests for static data. This is rightly being denied, as it means a malicious PHP script uploaded with a `.jpg` extension (for instance) will not be executed as PHP.

To resolve this issue, you need to pass only requests for PHP scripts under `/extras/` to PHP.

```
location ~ /extras/.*\.php$ {
```

If you need to handle static files under that directory specially, then you can make a `location` block for them. (You probably should do this, since you seem to be passing everything else to Django...)

```
location /extras/ { }
```

---

Another issue you have which is probably causing you grief is that your `server` block does not have a valid `root` defined. This is one of the most common [nginx misconfigurations](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/). It should be something like:

```
root /var/www/my_server;
```

(Which also means you should not define redundant `root`s in every single `location`.)