# nginx with php-fpm returns 403 when navigating to site

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have set up a server block for [my site](https://www.nativeleaf.co.uk) running on Nginx on a CentOS 7 VPS.

When I try and navigate to my website, I get a **403 Forbidden** error. This is apparently a common issue, but I couldn't relate to the answers I came across:

[Nginx and PHP-FPM 403 Forbidden](https://serverfault.com/questions/486368/nginx-and-php-fpm-403-forbidden/486374)

Here is the default nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  <my server ip>;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /var/www/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Here is the `.conf` for my site:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name nativeleaf.co.uk www.nativeleaf.co.uk;
  access_log /var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/access.log combined;
  root /var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk;

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

And here is the config for `php-fpm`:

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
[www]

; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
; Valid syntaxes are:
;   'ip.add.re.ss:port'    - to listen on a TCP socket to a specific address on
;                            a specific port;
;   'port'                 - to listen on a TCP socket to all addresses on a
;                            specific port;
;   '/path/to/unix/socket' - to listen on a unix socket.
; Note: This value is mandatory.
;listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock

; Set listen(2) backlog. A value of '-1' means unlimited.
; Default Value: -1
;listen.backlog = -1

; List of ipv4 addresses of FastCGI clients which are allowed to connect.
; Equivalent to the FCGI_WEB_SERVER_ADDRS environment variable in the original
; PHP FCGI (5.2.2+). Makes sense only with a tcp listening socket. Each address
; must be separated by a comma. If this value is left blank, connections will be
; accepted from any ip address.
; Default Value: any
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1

; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions.
; Default Values: user and group are set as the running user
;                 mode is set to 0666
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0750

; Unix user/group of processes
; Note: The user is mandatory. If the group is not set, the default user's group
;       will be used.
; RPM: apache Choosed to be able to access some dir as httpd
user = nginx
; RPM: Keep a group allowed to write in log dir.
group = nginx
```

**Logs Check**

When I do a `tail error.log` on the Nginx logs, I see this:

```
2018/04/26 14:54:01 [error] 12616#12616: *46 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "nativeleaf.co.uk"
2018/04/26 14:54:02 [error] 12616#12616: *46 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "nativeleaf.co.uk"
2018/04/26 14:54:03 [error] 12616#12616: *46 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "nativeleaf.co.uk"
2018/04/26 15:12:00 [error] 13495#13495: *5 "/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/what-is-yerba-mate/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 194.28.51.189, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET /what-is-yerba-mate/ HTTP/1.0", host: "www.nativeleaf.co.uk", referrer: "https://www.nativeleaf.co.uk/what-is-yerba-mate/"
2018/04/26 15:15:43 [error] 14163#14163: *7 directory index of "/var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.nativeleaf.co.uk"
2018/04/26 15:15:44 [error] 14163#14163: *7 directory index of "/var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.nativeleaf.co.uk"
2018/04/26 15:15:44 [error] 14163#14163: *7 directory index of "/var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "www.nativeleaf.co.uk"
```

The permissions are as follows on the folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 7 nginx  nginx   4096 Mar 26 07:07 nativeleaf.co.uk
```

As for the files inside, the permissions are:

```
-rw-r--r--.  1 nginx  nginx       418 Mar 23 11:39 index.php
```

Comment: Do you have `index.html` in `/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk`?

Comment: It is a wordpress site, so no, only `index.php`, `wp-config.php` ...etc. I've already listed `index.php` in the config, why must I have `index.html`?

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `/usr/share/nginx/html` to store your own web content. This directory is reserved for use by nginx and its own files, and your files may not be accessible there. Use one of the expected directories to store your files, i.e. `/srv/www` or `/var/www`.

Comment: Ok, say I moved my files to `/var/www/`, what setting(s) must I configure in nginx?

Comment: @MichaelHampton updated to use `/var/www/html`, I restart nginx and static sties work, but anything php (like WordPress) still gives **403 Forbidden**

Comment: OK, well now check nginx's error log.

Comment: Thanks, I just did, and I see `2018/04/26 14:54:01 [error] 12616#12616: *46 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/" is forbidden, client: 31.205.255.43, server: nativeleaf.co.uk, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "nativeleaf.co.uk"`, just updated the question with log info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `server` section for nativeleaf.co.uk doesn't define how to handle `PHP` files so it looks for `index.html` and as it doesn't exist fails with `directory index forbidden` error. The `server` section which you call default handles only requests with direct IP access and its settings have no effect on another `server` section.

Comment: I have updated the `.conf` file for the website (see original question) but I still get a **403 Forbidden**.

Comment: @Ciwan your config is still missing `index` and `location /` directives.

Comment: Thanks @AlexD, adding those missing bit got my homepage, but none of the other pages are working, I can't even get to the admin login page at `nativeleaf.co.uk/wp-admin`

Comment: @Ciwan again, look into your nginx error logs.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

from your configuration. Without this, nginx tries to look up only physical files on the system, and doesn't try to pass requests to WordPress (except for root URI /, which is passed to WordPress due to `index index.php;` setting).

Comment: Tero, right now [I have this](https://gist.github.com/Ciwan1859/fcee436be72a471a227de89bb9d9269b)

Answer (score 0):

your site  .conf file should look like this

```
server {
  listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server; #Enale it if your server have IPv6
  server_name nativeleaf.co.uk www.nativeleaf.co.uk;
  access_log /var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk/access.log combined;
  root /var/www/html/nativeleaf.co.uk;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }
  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }
}
```

this due Nginx default .conf file didn't include `index.php` parameter as default index file , so it gives you 403 error when can't find `index.html` file .