# NGINX 403 ACCESS DENIED

Tags: linux, nginx, php, laravel, rocky-linux

I have this problem in nginx, it is a Laravel application. but it is in a user's folder /home/user/projects, I already tried with 777 nginx owner of the folders but it still shows the error

```
 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Request Startup: Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0; Unable to open primary script: /home/pablo/Laravel-blade/public/index.php (Permission denied)" while reading response header from upstream, client: ......., server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "13......"
```

with error Access denied.
I have my permissions this way.

```
drwxr-xr-x.  3 nginx nginx   25 Mar  2 03:53 /home/
drwxr-xr-x.  6 nginx nginx  157 Mar  2 03:55 /home/pablo/
drwxrwxrwx. 15 nginx nginx 4096 Mar  2 03:55 /home/pablo/Laravel-blade/
drwxrwxrwx.  2 nginx nginx   77 Mar  2 03:55 /home/pablo/Laravel-blade/public/
-rwxrwxrwx+  1 nginx nginx 1710 Mar  2 03:55 /home/pablo/Laravel-blade/public/index.php
```

mi **www.conf**

```
user = nginx
group = nginx

listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660

;listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
```

mi **/etc/nginx/conf.d/laravel.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
#    server_name example.com;
    root /home/nginx-pablo/Laravel-blade/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        root /home/nginx-pablo/Laravel-blade/public;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;

#fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi.conf;
       include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It might be your `fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock` or actually your `fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;` Also: take a look at this config: https://serverfault.com/a/936806/203637 it has a `/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock` instead of a `www.sock`

Comment: home is always a bad idea for hosting applications. there is a reason why /var/www exists.

Comment: Additionally, globally writable web applications are dangerous. It seems you have tried to solve a problem but made the situation way worse. First, take a few steps back.

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled? Run `getenforce`.

Comment: Wait, `nginx` owns your home directory? And `/home`? That's probably *not* a good idea.

Comment: @djdomi yes but is bad practice, in var/www/ for more security in /home/usr

Comment: @AlexD yes but is bad practice, when setenforce 0, i give 500 error server

Comment: @vidarlo i change /home 
root owns, but the problem is the same

Comment: Ok, so the problem *is* SELinux, as you get a 500 when you disable SELinux. Host your application in a proper place (e.g. `/var/www`), and check your logs for why you get a 500 error.

Comment: maybe or not, when setenforce 0, the log is 
 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Request Startup: Failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0; Unable to open primary script: /home/nginx-pablo/Laravel-blade/public/index.php (Permission denied)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 12.33, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "122."

Answer (score 2):

As you have `SELinux` enabled you need to put your files into `/var/www/html` as this directory has `httpd_sys_content_t` context which allows read access to files for the `php-fpm`. Otherwise, you need to set the appropriate context yourself.

Comment: yup I agree, var/www is the place to go, and I don't see here any security issues. home is not more secure as any other folders that you create and use